# Facebook App Center Request "Play Now" Broken

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests, facebook-app-center

### QUESTION

In the FB App Center, my requests show up with the "Play Now" button. The URL for the "Play Now" button goes to `facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. Clicking on this takes me to a page that says "Sorry, this page isn't available". How do I get the "Play Now" button to take me to the App Details page like all the other apps I've seen?

### BACKGROUND

- It is a Unity game and we are using the new FB/Unity SDK. For this specific request, the function I'm calling is: `FB.AppRequest()`
- Our game is currently iOS only but we are adding full FB web support in a few months
- Our FB app is in sandbox mode
- The FB user I'm using to SEND the request is a developer on the FB app
- The FB user I'm using to RECEIVE the request is a tester on the FB app
- I have setup the basic information that seems to be required in `developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/appdetails`
- Since the game is currently iOS only, the only thing setup in the basic app settings is the "Native iOS App" portion

### OTHER INFO

I've been using Hay Day as an example because it is also iOS only. When I send myself a request from Hay Day, it shows up in the App Center->Requests section but it is slightly different.

Side-by-side comparison of the Hay Day request vs. our Tunnel Town request: [image]

Here is an example of the Hay Day appcenter page:
https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/haydaygame?fb_source=appcenter_request

Thanks so much for the help!